# Setting Text Color on Static UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

I have static cells and want to change text colour. I've made an outlet for the label. In the implementation i'm using 
`sine.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:191 green:48 blue:48 alpha:1.0];`

1. In this case the text colour shows white. However if I use `sine.textColor=[UIColor redColor];` it comes up red as expected. How?
2. Is there any way to change all text labels in one table view controller with one code (so i wouldn't need an outlet for every cell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  `UIColor` requires a `float` from 0-1. (That really bugs me too) You can divide values by 255.0  like:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:191.0f/255.0f green:48/255.0f blue:48/255.0f alpha:1.0]
```

In method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

set `cell.textColor = [UIColor yourColor];`

Comment: 1.I've done as you said but now tells me that `.textColor` was deprecated in iOS 3.0 so when I try to run it it crashes with SIGABRT.

2. Do I have to make on outlet from TableView or something?

Comment: You should be doing `[[cell detailTextLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor yourColor]];` and `[[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor yourColor]];` and not `[cell setTextColor:...];` as this has been deprecated for quite some time now.

Comment: OK it works fine now. In addition i had to make the code look like: `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor ...` It turns out the "textLabel" part was a necessity.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this for a STATIC cell is to create OUTLETS for all your cells, and change each individually... Otherwise you have to do this dynamically.

In your .h file:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myCell;
```

In your .m file

```
 [self.myCell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarification the colour change should look like: `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:191.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];` (from UIColor forward you can put whichever RGB values your heart desires) thanks Tier

However `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView) *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` doesn't work (for changing all cells' labels with one code ... maybe it's for DYNAMIC cells , however I'm looking for STATIC cells.